How do I turn a horizontal list group to a vertical list group?
In the following markup, I used these classes to make the list horizontal on small devices: list-group-horizontal-sm list-group. The problem is the horizontal style propagates to all larger devices. How do I make the list vertical on medium devices and larger?
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center col-12 col-md-2">
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-group-horizontal-sm list-group">
        <li>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="Screenshot from 2024-10-26 11-01-44.png" style="width: 47px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="Screenshot from 2024-10-26 11-01-44.png" style="width: 47px;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="img-fluid" src="Screenshot from 2024-10-26 11-01-44.png" style="width: 47px;" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


@media (min-width:768px) {
  .list-group-vertical-md {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

